# Swift - Restore NavigationBar border line

Tags: swift, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar, swift5

I'm working on an app and I want to hide the navigation bar completely in the first view controller as seen in screenshot 1 of [this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZiSsS.jpg). To do this I used the following lines in the first view controller.

```
    navigationController?.navigationBar.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(), for: .default)
    navigationController?.navigationBar.shadowImage = UIImage()
    navigationController?.navigationBar.isTranslucent = false
```

Now I want to restore the look of the navigation bar in my tableView view controller, so to do that I use the following lines:

```
    navigationController?.navigationBar.setBackgroundImage(nil, for: .default)
    navigationController?.navigationBar.shadowImage = nil
    navigationController?.navigationBar.barTintColor = nil
```

As a result the navigation bar looks like screenshot 2 in the [attached image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZiSsS.jpg). What I want to achieve is make it look like screenshot 3, with the separator line at the bottom. I'm not sure why it doesn't reappear when I restore the background and shadow images to nil.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out it's because I didn't set the isTranslucent property back to true.